# mysql how to replace part of a string that contains quotes

Tags: mysql

I have a table field called "**params**" with values like this (they are slightly different but the two names below are always the same):

```
{"lots_of_stuff,"frameborder":"0",lots_of_stuff,"pageclass_sfx":"",lots_of_stuff}
```

I need a script that will change "frameborder":"0" to "frameborder":"1" and "pageclass_sfx":"" to "pageclass_sfx":"1".

Please note that not all fields in params have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE tbl SET value = REPLACE(REPLACE(value, 'pageclass_sfx":""', 'pageclass_sfx":"1"'), 'frameborder":"0', 'frameborder":"1')
```

**Result**

```
|                                                                              VALUE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| {"lots_of_stuff,"frameborder":"1",lots_of_stuff,"pageclass_sfx":"1",lots_of_stuff} |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9301/1)

Comment: I tried that and got the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'

Comment: Value is the name of your column